# Too much transparancy in pgfplots

Tags: graphics, pgfplots

I try to embed pngs including transparancy into pgfplots. The problem is, that the transparancy is only around the main object of the png. However, as demonstrated by the MWE, it seems also to affect the entire PNG. How can I have the red dot in the attached image cover the dots behind it?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=6cm,
axis equal image,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,xmax=100.5,%
ymin=0.5,
ymax=100.5
]

\addplot[color=blue,
only marks,
mark size=0.4pt,
mark=*,
mark options={solid}]
table[row sep=crcr] {
10 10\\
50 50\\
};


\addplot[] graphics[xmin=0.5,xmax=100.5,%
ymin=0.5,
ymax=100.5
]{transparancyinpgfplots.png};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image: Including Image]

Comment: oh didn't notice, thanks for the heads up - but why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that the PNG is transparent, but rather that the plot markers are drawn on top of everything else (that's by design, so the markers don't get obscured by lines from other plots). You can change this behaviour by setting `clip mode=individual`, so all the plots are drawn in the order that you specify them:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=6cm,
axis equal image,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,xmax=100.5,%
ymin=0.5,
ymax=100.5,
clip mode=individual
]

\addplot[color=blue,
only marks,
mark size=0.4pt,
mark=*,
mark options={solid}]
table[row sep=crcr] {
10 10\\
50 50\\
};


\addplot graphics[xmin=0.5,xmax=100.5,%
ymin=0.5,
ymax=100.5
]{transparency.png};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```